# How can i add Missing Artifact in Maven Repository?

Tags: maven, struts, maven-3, maven-plugin, struts-1

I am beginner of struts framework. please help, how to add maven artifacts and plugin jar to maven repository because i got missing jar files in maven repository. any one pls help me........

Missing Libraries:

1. M2_REPO/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar
2. M2_REPO/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
3. M2_REPO/commons-chain/commons-chain/1.2/commons-chain-1.2.jar
4. M2_REPO/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar
5. M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
6. M2_REPO/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.3.1/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
7. M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
8. M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/struts-core/1.3.10/struts-core-1.3.10.jar
9. M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/struts-taglib/1.3.10/struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar
10. M2_REPO/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar

Comment: How did you try to start working on this project? Are you using a Maven Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Thank you sir(Dave Newton). yes, am using maven.then am manually add missing jar files in maven repository. i have another one doubt, why using custom tags in jsp,struts,etc.... what is benefit of using custom tags. any example? pls help me......

Comment: Those files are in the central repository, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If we are using maven application.For every missing jar,we need to search maven dependency and add it pom.xml,while mvn:install the jars will be downloaded into mavenrepository

Answer (score 1):

First step: add dependency to pom.xml file. For example:

```
<dependencies>
........
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>oro</groupId>
    <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
........
</dependencies>
```

All declaration you get at http://mvnrepository.com/

I don't work with struts, but all libraries are in maven cental repository.

Next step, run install command from project root dir (in shell, for example). All dependencies may be downloading automatically:

```
mvn install
```

If download of dependencies failed you may install them in local repo manually (previously downloaded to disk), for example:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path-to-file/oro-2.0.8.jar -DgroupId=oro -DartifactId=oro -Dversion=2.0.8 -Dpackaging=jar
```

install guide http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Thanks, that helped.  This should be marked as answer